# Write file to blob storage and save the SaS URL using C#

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create an Azure Function that create files in blob storage and then save a pre-signed blob file url that is generated dynamically in an azure table so that we can return blob file url to the client program to open.

I am able to create the files in blob storage and save the urls. Right now, the code makes the file urls public, I am not sure how can I make the current code generate SaS url instead of public url and save it to the azure table.

I didn't see any example that shows the usage of `CloudBlobClient` and `SaS`. Appreciate any help.

```
[FunctionName("CreateFiles")]
public static async void Run([QueueTrigger("JobQueue", Connection = "")]string myQueueItem,
    [Table("SubJobTable", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudTable subJobTable,
    ILogger log)
{
    Job job = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Job>(myQueueItem);

    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    string containerName = $"{job.Name.ToLowerInvariant()}{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";
    CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer =
        cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

    BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions
    {
            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
    };
    cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissions(permissions);

    string localPath = "./data/";
    string localFileName = $"{job.Id}.json";
    string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, localFileName);
    File.WriteAllText(localFilePath, myQueueItem);
    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(localFileName);
    log.LogInformation("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
    cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(localFilePath);

    // update the table with file uri
    DynamicTableEntity entity = new DynamicTableEntity(job.Id, job.PracticeId);
    entity.Properties.Add("FileUri", new EntityProperty(cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    entity.Properties.Add("Status", new EntityProperty("Complete"));
    TableOperation mergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);
    subJobTable.Execute(mergeOperation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that your code is making use of the older version of the SDK (Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob). If that's the case, then you would need to use [`GetSharedAccessSignature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.getsharedaccesssignature?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) method in [`CloudBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) to generate a shared access signature token.

Your code would be something like:

```
...
cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(localFilePath);
var sasToken = cloudBlockBlob. GetSharedAccessSignature(sas-token-parameters);
var sasUrl = "${cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri}?${sasToken}";//Add question mark only if sas token does not have it.
...
```